# How to convert the string into a fixed int 2D array(special case)?

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array

Here is my string
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

a string combined with 60 1/0.

I want to put it into a int Array[6][10].
I tried to add "," between each row, but it failed

```
String data = "1000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000";
String[] rows = data.split(",");

String[][] matrix = new String[rows.length][];
int r = 0; 
for (String row : rows) { 
   matrix[r++] = row.split("\\|"); 
}
System.out.print(matrix);
```

Please help and solve this problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very straightforward solution that does not require splitting on  `regex` or inserting commas:

```
String input = "100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
int[][] matrix = new int[6][10];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(input.charAt(i * 10 + j) + "");
```

Comment: you just snatched it from me by few seconds.

Comment: it shows "Type mismatch: cannot convert from char to String" 
matrix[i][j] = input.charAt(i * 10 + j);

Comment: Moreover, I forget to tell that I want to convert to int 2D array instead of string 2D array. Sorry about that.

Comment: @user3451500, my latest edit fixes the first issue. If you want to convert to `int`, we can wrap with `parseInt()`. I will update again.

Comment: public static void StringToArray(String _Input){
     String input = _Input;
     int[][] matrix = new int[6][10];
     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
         matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(input.charAt(i * 10 + j) + "");
     System.out.println( Arrays.toString(matrix ) );
    }


at roomBooking.Storage.StringToArray(Storage.java:122)
 at roomBooking.Storage.main(Storage.java:135)


My programme is checking a array from a text whether there is 1/0, if 1 return true, else return false.

Comment: Can't you just put `matrix[i][j] = input.charAt(i*10+j)-'0';` on the last line?

Comment: @DavidWallace, That certainly also works, but subtracting the value of `'0'` is arguably less readable for a beginner.

Comment: @user3451500, I'm not sure whether you are trying to ask a new question, or just making a comment. If you are trying to ask a new question, I'd recommend putting it into a new question, since it's very difficult to read your code in the comment, and equally difficult to tell what you're asking.